# call function in parent tab from child tab in the browser in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have provided hyperlink on parent page and on clicking of this hyperlink it open new tab in same browser and new opened tab has one button.What i wanted to do that onclick of this button i wanted to call function present in parent tab.We can solve this by using javascript but how to achieve this in angular 2.

Comment: by window are you refereing to **componenet**

Comment: yes parent window has one component and child window has another component but both are using same service.

Comment: what did try so far and what issue are you facing ?

Comment: i tried EventEmitter for achieving this but it worked only for same page, it not accessed anything on the parent tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the parent tabs component type statically, you can inject the parent into the child:

```
constructor(parent:ParentTabComponent) {
  parent.foo();
}
```